# Can I go out of the ICN airport without visa as an Indonesia Citizen?

Tags: transit, indonesian-citizens, icn

I'm an Indonesian citizen, I am travelling to the USA.
I have a transit in the South Korean ICN airport for 12 hours, am I allowed to leave the airport without visa?

Answer (score 1):

Indonesian nationals normally need a visa to visit South Korea, but when you have a USA visa and are on a journey to or from the USA you can use the [transit tourist program](http://english.visitkorea.or.kr/enu/TRP/TP_ENG_8_5.jsp) to take one of several short guided tours. Stop at the Transit Tour desk in Terminal 1 or Terminal 2 to book a tour.